# Unable to reliably bind to attached property as source

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, attached-properties, windows-10-universal

Why does the Binding work for the individual `TextBlock` but not work for the `TextBlock` inside the `Button.Flyout`.

```
<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <RichTextBlock Name="rtbMain" attc:RichTextBlockAttached.CurrentFlyoutText="Trial Attached Binding" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True">
        <Paragraph>
            Button Flyout should display Trial Attached Binding
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="btt" RelativePanel.Below="rtbMain" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith="rtbMain" Content="Click to test binding">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(attc:RichTextBlockAttached.CurrentFlyoutText), ElementName=rtbMain, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock RelativePanel.Below="btt" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith="btt" Text="{Binding Path=(attc:RichTextBlockAttached.CurrentFlyoutText), ElementName=rtbMain, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

and attached property definition:

```
    public static class RichTextBlockAttached
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentFlyoutTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "CurrentFlyoutText",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(RichTextBlockAttached),
            new PropertyMetadata("", OnCurrentFlyoutTextChanged));

    private static void OnCurrentFlyoutTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static string GetCurrentFlyoutText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(CurrentFlyoutTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCurrentFlyoutText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CurrentFlyoutTextProperty, value);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not used to creating bindings from C#, but I think the issue could come from the namespace: if you created the binding from the XAML, you'd have at some point to set the namespace for RichTextBlockIncludedRules (something like `local:RichTextBlockIncludedRules.CurrentFlyoutText`). I don't know how you're supposed to provide this information but it's clear that it's missing

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. But it seems like maybe you are trying to use an attached property as the _source_ for a binding? If so, I don't believe you can do that. Instead, you should provide a model data structure that is used as the source for both the attached property and your binding here. If you are trying to do something different, please simplify your code example, and provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you are trying to do. Be sure to explain what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have edited my original question with updated info. I realised that I don't need to apply the binding in code behind, and thus the XAML component and edit should help make my intent more clear. Hopefully you are wrong and I can use the attachedproperty as the binding source.

Comment: _"except that the Flyout only shows the second TextBlock.Text value"_ -- so, doesn't work. I.e. the attached property doesn't work as the source path. You should start by looking at the debug output for any binding error message. Beyond that, you should reread (read?) the link describing a good [mcve] that I provided earlier. The code above is incomplete, and yet includes a lot of pieces that surely are not needed to reproduce the specific issue you're having.

Comment: Using the advice in your link, I have narrowed down the issue and adjusted my question accordingly. The issue is not around the attached property being the source, but the binding not working as expected inside the `Flyout`. As per the adjusted code, the final `TextBlock` correctly displays the value keyed into the attached property, but the `TextBlock` inside the `Flyout` doesn't. I haven't been able to locate the cause/reason.